# After my app is suspended by the system, the Initial View Controller does not load properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm having an issue that exclusively occurs when I launch my app after it was suspended (while in background) by iOS. In any other situation, the issue won't occur - which already is quite weird. As using the XCode debugger prevent suspension of the app when it goes to background, I have been collecting logs through the Unified Logging system to investigate.

The logs indicate that when I launch the app after suspension by the system, the storyboard scene that is defined as Initial View Controller does get displayed but the code that sits in the viewDidLoad() function of the associated view controller class is not being run.

This happens exclusively after suspension by the system, and will never happen if I manually (or through the XCode stop button) kill the app and relaunch it.

I'm totally stuck as I don't understand why this is happening and why there would be a difference induced by the system suspension.

My project is declaring the main storyboard as "Main Interface" in the target settings. In this storyboard, a scene is defined as Initial View Controller. This scene has a custom class defined, and when I click the arrow next to the custom class name, XCode does take me to the class declaration code.

The class declaration code looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import os.log


class InitialLoadViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//custom code

}
}
```

The custom code starts with a logging statement that I don't see printed when the issue occurs.

Hope someone may have an idea about what's happening!

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lof of debugging I found out my issue was related to some of my app background activities. My app is sometimes receiving silent push notifications that wakes it up in the background to perform a network call that refreshes some local data. This process in itself was working well, but waking up my app in the background was also instantiating some view controllers (ie starting up my UI). But my UI has some dependancy to additional network calls that were not designed to work while the app is active in the background. They were therefore failing and leaving the UI in  a fail condition that was not handled when the app is in background.

So I have now basically conditioned some aspects of launching my UI to having my app active in the foreground, rather than just having my app active.

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong, but I believe that while your app is not getting reloaded, it is disappearing. Try using **viewDidAppear** or **viewWillAppear** instead of viewDidLoad for the code you want to be executed after suspension.